# value inside a linked lists Node exists after change, why?

Tags: c, malloc, free

lets say we have a linked list = [1] -> [2] -> [3] -> [4]

```
typedef struct Node
{
    int val;
    struct Node* next;
}Node;
```

I have the head and to free all the allocated memory I do

```
printf("%i", head->val); // prints 1

Node* tmp = head;
while(tmp != NULL)
{
    Node* tmp2 = tmp;
    tmp = tmp->next;
    free(tmp2);
}

printf("%i", head->val); // prints a big number, but exists and is not NULL

if (tmp == NULL)
{
    print("is null"); // this prints too
}
```

why head->val still exists and tmp doesn't? shouldn't head->val be NULL after freeing it ?
I assumed since head is a pointer itself and i set it to another pointer then its pointing at the location anyway so when I free tmp it should free the thing in the address that head is pointing to aswell?

Comment: You're invoking undefined behaviour by accessing the object pointed to by `head` after freeing it. `tmp` is `NULL` from traversing the list to the end, but you never update `head` to be `NULL`. Even if you did, accessing `head->val` would still be undefined behaviour, and likely result in a program crash.

Comment: so head is free'd and that number is simply because im trying to access something within the head that is pointing to some random address?

Comment: It doesn't "have" a value *per se*. You're just reading some memory in the heap, where your object used to be, which happens to contain some big number.

Comment: Thank you, this was the answer I was looking for

Comment: When you free something, the memory becomes available to subsequent calls to `malloc` etc.  That doesn't mean it will be immediately zeroed.  It could be, but that would slow it down, right?  The point of coding in C, rather than a higher-level language, is that it's lean and fast.  That means it skips a lot of runtime debugging checks.  If you feel you need those checks, then use an interpreted language and don't bother with the speed advantages of C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in comments, attempting to access member of `head` after freeing it invokes undefined behavior. `head->val` might be `NULL`, or it might still have a value because that memory has not been overwritten.

The point of *undefined* in "undefined behavior" is that we don't know and can't know for sure what will happen.